# How to make multiple rows into columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I've tried MAX CASE WHEN and CTE but for some reason can't exactly figure this out.

My data looks like this:

```
SELECT RC, isMHy, eligible
FROM test

RC      isMHY   eligible
190B05  0       1
190K00  1       0
```

There can be up to 4 rows in the table, I want to the results to look like this (12 columns in case there are 4 rows)

```
 RC1    isMHY1  eligible1   RC2    isMHY2   eligible2
 190B05 0       1           190K00 1        0
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: Can you be more clear?

Comment: If there were a third row in your sample, would there be a second row in your output, or would there be 3 more columns in your output? It's unclear from your example what logic would be used to associate two rows from your source into one row of output..

Comment: Sorry, yes it can go up to 4 rows. I want to get the associated rows into one row going across. Each RC is attached to one isMhy and eligible as seen above.

Comment: Can there be 10 rows for exapme? What would happen? 3 rows(2x4 + 1x2) ?

Comment: sagi, there can be up to 4 rows only. So that would be 12 columns going across. 3 for each row.

Comment: Please edit your question to contain the other details and more.

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional aggregation with `ROW_NUMBER()` :

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN s.rnk = 1 THEN s.rc END) as rc1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.rnk = 1 THEN s.ismhy END) as ismhy1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.rnk = 1 THEN s.eligible END) as eligible1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.rnk = 2 THEN s.rc END) as rc2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.rnk = 2 THEN s.ismhy END) as ismhy2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.rnk = 2 THEN s.eligible END) as eligible2,
       ..........
FROM(
    SELECT t.*,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SELECT 1) as rnk
    FROM test t) s
```

Comment: in case of 1000 rows?

Comment: @Ullas Look at the comments of this question "up to 4 rows only"